# Configuring TinyTex to work with LyX

Tags: lyx, installing, tinytex

I decided to migrate my `texlive-full` installation to something more lightweight,such  as TinyTex. I usually like to write documents in LyX.

I ran `sudo apt remove texlive-full` and successfully uninstalled TexLive. Then, downloaded the latest version of TinyTeX, and added the LaTeX binaries to my `PATH` via `export PATH="$PATH:/home/myname/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux/"`. This has been added to my `.bashrc` file, and updated via `source .bashrc`.

All the procedure described above works as intended. I checked that I compile my already existing `.tex` files from the terminal just invoking `pdflatex`. Of course, I needed to install some packages via `tlmgr`, but this is expected.

The problem comes when I want to use LyX. When I try to create a new document, I get an error saying that `The selected document class Article (Standard Class) requires external files that are not available. The document class can still be used, but the document cannot be compiled until the following prerequisites are installed: article.cls`.

Apparently, LyX cannot find any of the classes. I have been already reading several related questions, which lead me to try the following:

- Trying to `Reconfigure` LyX. I also tried going to `Preferences > Routes` and using the `PATH prefix` option, with different routes, such as `/home/myname/.TinyTeX/bin/x86_64-linux` `/home/myname/.TinyTeX/`, `/home/myname/.TinyTeX/textmf-local/` or `/home/myname/.TinyTeX/textmf-dist/`.
- Trying to set the variables `TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME` to some of the previously mentioned values. Apparently, LyX uses these variables to find custom classes, so I thought that maybe it expects them to be defined. In particular, I tried to `export TEXMFLOCAL=/home/myname/.TinyTeX/textmf-local/` and then setting `TEXMFHOME` to different combinations, with no luck.
- Reinstalling again LyX with `sudo apt remove lyx` and `sudo apt install lyx`. This did not solved the problem (it also additionally installed a `texlive-base` package, but strangely, the `article.cls` file still was not found. I uninstalled this package again).

What is the correct way to set up correctly an installation of TinyTex + LyX? Am I missing any important step? My system is Ubuntu 16.04, in case it is relevant.

`